# Etymology of 'banner' to mean 'outstanding'

Tags: etymology, adjectives, american-english, colloquialisms

'Banner' seems to have an alternative meaning which can be found in several dictionaries. For taste, here's [Wiktionary's](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/banner) definition for it:

> **banner**: Exceptional; very good.
>
> ---
>
> [*1853, New-Hampshire Missionary Society, Annual Report of the Trustees of the New Hampshire Missionary Society, Volumes 50-57, volume 53, Steam power press of McFarland & Jenks, page 16*]
>
> > The year just closed has been the **banner** year for New Hampshire Home Missions. The amount raised for the cause is $505,38 more than ever was raised before in any one year.
>
> [*2016, David M. Kennedy; Lizabeth Cohen; Mel Piehl, The Brief American Pageant: A History of the Republic, page 73*]
>
> > The Zenger decision was a **banner** achievement for freedom of the press. It pointed the way to the kind of open public discussion required by the diverse society that colonial New York already was and that all America was to become.

It seems to go pretty far back, as the first example shows, but is still used today. And I often see the phrase 'banner year.'

So what is the origin of this usage?

Comment: I've got to say I've never heard the word used in that sense. Dictionaries tell me that it is a valid meaning in North America, though. Without an example, I presume that it comes from the idea of celebrating or proclaiming a notable success: circumstances in which you'd display a banner.

Comment: I've always assumed that the term relates to having a "banner" -- a strip of cloth that's sort of like a flag.  It's not unusual to have such a cloth strip on poles being held above a group of people who are being celebrated.

Answer (score 2):

*Banner* is related to *band* (as in a band of cloth or a band of color across a cloth) and has long meant a distinctive flag around which a group (Dare I say "band"?) of people might rally.  The *OED* traces the usage of *banner* as a flag of award and it's attributive sense of award-winning to 1840 in the US.  The dictionary's cites include a "banner state," "banner plantation," and "banner crop" -- all meaning worthy of an award for excellence.

*Banner" meaning a type of newspaper headline (i.e., a band of large, distinctive type) doesn't show up (again in the US) until 1913,

Comment: Great.  Another DBDV, a plague on this site.

Comment: What on earth does DBDV stand for?

Comment: @HollyK Sorry, I'm kind of muttering to myself here.  DBDV stands for (D)rive-(B)y (D)own (V)ote, a down vote with no explanation of what might be wrong or need improvement.  It's idiosyncratic to me.

Answer (score 0):

***Reference work coverage of 'banner as an adjective***

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) identifies two meanings of banner as an adjective and traces the first of these to 1840:

> **banner** *adj* (1840) **1 :** prominent in support of a political party <a *banner* Democratic county> **2 :** distinguished from all others esp. in excellence <a *banner* year for business>

The political orientation of the earlier definition would suggest that "a banner county [or similar noun]" arose in the sense of "a county [or other noun] that metaphorically carried the banner for a particular political party or cause." Richard Thornton, *An American Glossary* (1962) reinforces this impression with the following entry:

> **Banner State.** The one which roles up the greatest vote in an election, or which in any way surpasses the others.
>
> > **1840** Which is the *Banner State*?—The Whigs at an early stage of the electioneering for the next president, proposed to designate whichever state should give the [William Henry] Harrison ticket the largest majority, as the *banner state*, There has been considerable rivalry for the honor.—[*Niles's Register*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AwJBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA210&dq=%22banner+state%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnrKOD7I__AhXLAjQIHcvfAzYQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22banner%20state%22&f=false), Dec. 5, p. 210/1.
> >
> > **1840** *The banner county*.—Designation is claimed by Worcester, Massachusetts, which gave Harrison the largest aggregate majority, viz: 4,773.—[*Id.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AwJBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA210&dq=%22banner+state%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnrKOD7I__AhXLAjQIHcvfAzYQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22banner%20county%22&f=false), Dec. 5.
> >
> > **1841** An attempt to prove that Vermont, and not Kentucky, was entitled to the honor of "the *Banner State*."—Henry Clay in the U.S. Senate, March 1 : [*Cong[ressional] Globe*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mj8uAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA3-PA332&dq=%22banner+state%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf0dvU8I__AhVFLn0KHZpTAJE4FBDoAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22banner%20state%22&f=false), p.332, App.
> >
> > **1850** Mr. M. is a native of New Jersey, the good old "*banner State*" of the revolution.—Theodore T. Johnson, 'Sights in the Gold Region,' p. 154 (N.Y.)
> >
> > **1862** Illinois is still the *banner State*.—*Knickerbocker Mag.*, lx. 371 (Oct.)

---

***Early occurrences of 'banner state/county/town'***

Elephind newspaper database searches turn up several instances from the weeks immediately before before the term's December 5, 1840, appearance in the *Niles Weekly Journal*, cited by Thornton.

I couldn't confirm the earliest of these matches because it is housed at the Pennsylvania State University newspaper collection, which has been offline for several months now. The gist of the reference, as cited in an Elephind thumbnail from an item published in the *Gettysburg [Pennsylvania] Star* (November 10, 1840) is as follows:

> ... Harrison to the core, and will probably be the Whig **banner State**. Connecticut. Nobly and gallantly has this State done her duty. The true hearted sons of the "land of steady habits," have given the Harrison electoral ticket a ...

From "[Vermont the Banner State](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84023252/1840-11-24/ed-1/seq-2/#words=%22banner%2Bstate%22)," in the *[St. Johnsbury, Vermont] Caledonian* (November 24, 1840):

> Our majority of over 14,000 overreaches all the other States in proportion to the number of votes given in the State. Rhode IslandJ is the nearest to our heels, but if we are not mistaken we could spare about a thousand and a half and then beat our ambitious competitor. Louisiana, though she has done nobly, is behind Rhode Island. Ours, then, is the '***Banner State***.' And what State deserves the compliment more than Vermont?

From "[King William—*The Democratic Standard-Bearer*](https://virginiachronicle.com/?a=d&d=RE18401201.1.3&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22banner+county%22-------)," in the *Richmond [Virginia] Enquirer* (December 1, 1840):

> And now, when the Democratic party is declared to be annihilated, by the Whigs, never, never to rise again, we nee the veteran Editor of the Enquirer unfurling the Flag of '98—on the 20th November. King William [county] is the first to rally to it, and bear it aloft to the breeze. Does this not entitle her to be called the ***Banner County***?

And from another unconfirmed match, this time in the *Carlisle [Pennsylvania] Herald and Expositor* (December 2, 1840):

> **The Flag County in Tennessee**— Sevier county, in Tennessee, is the **banner county** in that State. It is familiarly known as "Little Kentucky." Its rivals for the banner were Jefferson, ("Little Massachusetts,") and Cocke and Carter.

From these instances it seems fairly clear that "banner state" (soon to be extended to "banner county") originated as a promotional device by the Whig Party in the United States to challenge different parts of the country that were heavily pro-Whig to compete with each other to turn out the largest majority in favor of their candidate in the 1840 Presidential election.

This usage didn't remain limited to U.S. Presidential election politics for long, however.

One early purveyor of "banner X" designations was the *Journal of the American Temperance Union*, which in its March 1841 issue included this [untitled item](https://books.google.com/books?id=j4FPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA44&dq=%22banner+state%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi677CL7Y__AhUvHTQIHYhnAcI4ChDoAXoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22banner%20state%22&f=false):

> THE **BANNER STATE**.—The Philadelphia North American says, there is not in the gallant little State of Delaware a single distillery to be found. The lovers of antiquity can be gratified with a view of the ruins of an old one on the banks of the Brandywine.

This follows earlier citations of Machisas, Maine, and Wethersfield, Connecticut as banner towns of temperance, and York, Maine, as "the banner town of intemperance." That designation also appears in "[A Hopeful Town](https://books.google.com/books?id=UqbQAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA360&dq=%22banner+town%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj-82i8o__AhWiHzQIHVAVD004HhDoAXoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22banner%20town%22&f=false)," in Horace Greeley's *The New-Yorker* (February 20, 1841), which quotes the report of the York County auxiliary of the Maine Temperance Society as follows:

> The town [York] now polls 740 votes ; and by referring to the check list, 183 of them, just one fourth part, are ascertained to be drunkards, or in the habit of occasionally drinking to intoxication. The sum of about $7,000 is annually expended for rum, a sum sufficient to pay all the taxes, or to purchase two of the best farms in town, to say nothing of the squandered time, and other losses  incident to drunkenness. I am not certain, unless the capital of the State may with propriety claim the distinction, but that York must be regarded as the **banner town** as regards intemperance.

Moving slightly farther afield, the June 1 issue of the *Journal of the American Temperance Union* cites Connecticut as "the banner State in all fiscal concerns."

G.J. Grosvenor, "[Progress of the Cause in Central New York](https://books.google.com/books?id=j4FPAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA2-PA54&dq=%22banner+county%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijvYiZ5Y__AhV7FzQIHV6SBw44FBDoAXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22banner%20county%22&f=false)," in *[New York] Journal of the American Temperance Union* (April 1842) uses "banner county" in connection with abstinence from alcohol:

> We now come to Seneca county, to which has very generally, and I believe justly, been conceded the palm in the production of wheat; and I am not certain but that she is also entitled to the proud distinction of the "**banner county**" in the temperance enterprise. Be this as it may, to her flourishing and enterprising villages, Waterloo and Seneca Falls, fairly belong the honor of originating and setting in motion in this part of the county the mighty moral revolution whose results we are recording.

William Lincoln, "[Report on Swine at Albany](https://books.google.com/books?id=Dmu0v3c9q8MC&pg=RA2-PA163&dq=%22banner+county%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjy_szY54__AhXfHjQIHagRAmU4RhDoAXoECA4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22banner%20county%22&f=false)," in the *[Boston, Massachusetts] New England Farmer, and Horticultural Register* (November 23, 1842) applies the term not to the state legislature, but to pigs:

> The Judges of Swine, of the New York State Agricultural Society, respectfully submit their report: They have the great honor of waiting on a great company of those amiable animals, who claim our warmest affections, by all those dear relations which connect the pots and plates of those who desire to live well. The pigs have made Albany the "**banner county**" of pork. They sent no delegates to the State convention of stock ; they attended in person, and formed one magnificent "mass meeting." Seventy swine were present, and deserved seventy premiums.

And E.W. Brewster, "[Review of the Cultivator, November No.](https://books.google.com/books?id=9vsjAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA16&dq=%22banner+county%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT-d7L5Y__AhXuAjQIHZAkBac4PBDoAXoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22banner%20county%22&f=false)" in the *[Chicago, Illinois] Prairie Farmer* applies "banner county" to butter production:

> In Butter, three of the five premiums awarded went to Orange county [New York], one to Oneida and one to Columbia. Thus old Orange yet maintains her claim as the "**banner county**" for butter.

---

***Early occurrences of 'banner year/day'***

The jump from *banner* in the sense of "award-worthy" as applied to political factions, teetotalers, pigs, and butter to *banner* in the sense of "outstanding or especially notable period of time" may not have occurred until the early 1850s. I didn't find any instances of "banner [time period]" older than the instance of "banner year" from "[Fifty-Second Annual Report of the Trustees of the New-Hampshire Missionary Society](https://books.google.com/books?id=7BQQAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA2-PA16&dq=%22banner+year%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij2rCe3I__AhXyIzQIHQUqDq8Q6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22banner%20year%22&f=false)" (August 25, 1853), which is mentioned in the posted question above.

But slightly after the New Hampshire instance, an instance of "banner day" appears. From "[The State Fair at Dayton](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85038121/1853-09-29/ed-1/seq-2/#words=%22banner%2Bday%22)," in the *Gallipolis [Ohio] Journal* (September 29, 1853), reprinted from the *Cincinnati [Ohio] Times*:

> A great crowd was here on Wednesday—a sight at which was sufficient to repay a Cincinnatian for the trip up; but yesterday was the **banner day**. Such a tremendous gathering of people never before took place in Ohio. It was estimated by some that 100,000 persons were present on Wednesday; others guessed half that number.—What ever it was, every body thought the whole State was present.

---

***Conclusions***

Instances of banner in the sense of most overwhelmingly in favor of a particular political party seem to have arisen in late 1840 in connection with the Whig party's electoral campaign on behalf of William Henry Harrison for U.S. President. Evidently the Whigs challenged different states to compete against each other to determine which one would give Harrison the largest (or proportionately the largest) margin of victory in the 1840 election.

Within a couple of years "banner state" and "banner county" were being applied to non-electoral matters such as temperance and then to entirely nonpolitical topics such as farm animals, crops, and dairy products.

This shift probably set the stage for a shift in meaning from "region with the best record of success" to "time when the best production (of whatever kind)" occurred. However, this new meaning didn't appear in print until the early 1850s (probably). The New Hampshire Missionary Society's "banner year," reported in late August 1853, involved fundraising. The banner day at the Ohio State Fair in Dayton, Ohio, reported approximately one month after that, involved crowd size.

When most people think of Harrison's Presidential campaign in 1840, which was substantially longer than his actual Presidency, they think of the slogan "Tippecanoe and Tyler, too"—the former being the site of a significant battle between U.S. troops and Native American forces allied with Tecumseh, and the latter being Harrison's chosen vice-presidential candidate. But in practical terms, the idiomatic phrase "a banner [noun]" may be the more significant and lasting contribution to everyday U.S. English that arose out of Harrison's campaign.